# Giving upload option in InfoPath form in SPD workflow

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, infopath

I have made a 2010 style workflow in SPD. In one of the step I have added a task form so user can approve item. SharePoint has automatically created InfoPath form for me. How can I give option to user to upload a file in that form?

Workflow type is 2010 but SharePoint and InfoPath version is 2013.

Comment: Hi @frank where you need to save the uploaded file ?

Comment: Anywhere suitable for e.g. in a library.

Comment: Anyone??? I can't find a single solution to this problem. Where is file attachment control in InfoPath?

Answer (score 0):

In InfoPath there is an attachment field you can use.
Make sure you turned on the attachments in your task list?

- List Settings
- Advanced Settings
- Attachments

Comment: That attachment field is actually just a text box where you can enter URL of file which you have to upload separately in a library.